# Laravel accessing optional route group prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I want to generalize some common routes within a route group like the following:

```
# Administrative routes

Route::group(array('prefix' => '{word}'), function($parameter) {

    // $table = $parameter->...?

    Route::post('restore', ['as'=>$table.'.restore', 'uses'=>ucfirst($table).'Controller@restore']);
    Route::get('{id}/suspend', ['as'=>$table.'.suspend', 'uses'=>ucfirst($table).'Controller@suspend']);
    Route::get('{id}/activate', ['as'=>$table.'.activate', 'uses'=>ucfirst($table).'Controller@activate']);
});
```

But I dont know how to use the $parameter passed through the callback function.

How can I fetch the route prefix string from the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Oh well... it should be this simple:

```
# Administrative routes

Route::group(array('prefix' => '{word}'), function($parameter) {

    $table = Request::segment(1);
    $controller = ucfirst($table).'Controller';

    Route::post('restore', ['as'=>$table.'.restore', 'uses'=>$controller.'@restore']);
    Route::get('{id}/suspend', ['as'=>$table.'.suspend', 'uses'=>$controller.'@suspend']);
    Route::get('{id}/activate', ['as'=>$table.'.activate', 'uses'=>$controller.'@activate']);
});
```

If you can fetch it from the function $parameter feel free to share how.